# Como ocultar arquivos no GitHub?

Tags: git, github, heroku, senhas, variáveis-de-ambiente

Quero deixar alguns projetos do meu GitHub públicos, mas alguns arquivos deles possuem informações confidenciais (como senhas de acesso a banco de dados).

É possível deixar esses arquivos específicos ocultos para que as pessoas vejam somente os outros arquivos?

Sei que dá pra fazer isso escrevendo o nome do arquivo no `.gitignore`, mas também quero fazer deploy desses projetos no Heroku usando o repositório do GitHub. Quando faço isso, o Heroku não reconhece os arquivos que foram descritos no `.gitignore` e a aplicação dá erro.

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso. Talvez você devesse considerar ter essas configurações em outra fonte como variáveis de ambiente ou aplicações feitas pra isso.

Comment: Entendi, valeu pela dica!

Comment: Se é uma estrutura nova e quer fazer algo bem feito, recomendo dar uma olhada no Azure KeyVault que é feito exatamente pra isso: https://docs.microsoft.com/PT-BR/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts

Comment: Nunca coloque senhas no github. Isso é uma falha tremenda de segurança.

Answer (score 1):

Não inclua arquivos de senhas no Git. Como você comentou, você usa GitHub e Heroku. Isso abre duas opções.

1. Automatizar seu deploy com GitHub Actions, que suporta [secrets](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets). Esses valores secretos vão ficar disponíveis no fluxo de deploy dentro do Actions.
2. Usar [variáveis de ambiente no Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) e consumi-las na sua aplicação. Você pode configurar na sua aplicação dentro do Heroku uma lista de variáveis de ambiente, por exemplo `DATABASE_URL`, `DATABASE_PASSWORD`. Os valores ficam fora do código, e você não expõe nada.

Lembrando que ao subir seu projeto Git pro GitHub, os commits históricos terão as suas senhas. Por isso, recomendo que use o [`git-forget-blob`](https://github.com/nachoparker/git-forget-blob), e confira mil vezes ao subir pro remoto.

```sh
# "esquece" os arquivos do histórico do git
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nachoparker/git-forget-blob/master/git-forget-blob.sh -O /usr/local/bin/git-forget-blob
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-forget-blob

git-forget-blob /arquivo/para/esquecer.txt
git-forget-blob /arquivo/para/esquecer-2.txt
git-forget-blob /arquivo/para/esquecer-3.txt

# faz um push sobrescrevendo o remoto, caso não tenham
# alterações mais novas por lá
git push origin <branch> --force-with-lease
```